# Access Primavera P6 Data from C# web api code

Tags: c#, primavera

I added connected services for my project on the following URL: https://example.com:8219/p6ws/services/AuthenticationService

Then I've tried to do something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676383/how-to-read-and-write-data-in-p6db-via-p6-web-service-using-c-sharp), but the AuthenticationService does not contain CookieContainer / Login method. And I'm stuck, whether the endpoint is wrong, I missed something.

Comment: Shouldn't you check the docs for that? SO is a Q&A site for specific programming questions. What you ask is part of the product's documentation. Web API is a *server* technology, it has nothing to do with how you call other services. Since Primavera uses SOAP, you can create a client with `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio

Comment: I suspect this is the first time you used StackOverflow and don't understand how it works, or what makes a good question. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saying `Tell me how to do X` without showing any kind of effort isn't a good question. Asking people to give you a tutorial is one of the predefined reasons to close a question. Comments like `Answer me or don't bother me` are going to get flagged

Comment: Have you tried just googling `primavera soap login`? One of the first results is [Authentication Using HTTP Cookies](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E90746_01/English/Integration_Documentation/p6_eppm_web_services_programming/helpmain.htm?toc.htm?34311.htm). There's an entire section on authentication there. There are *several* different ways, but you didn't explain which one you want. `WSDL` means this is a SOAP service. To create a client for any web service in Visual Studio, you use `Add Service Reference`. Have you tried any of the documented ways to login? Are you asking about a specific one?

Comment: See above, I've specified things I've done.